# How to search a string for the first and second occurance of military time in python

Tags: python, string, web-scraping

So I'm doing some scraping in my django application.

The thing that I get when scraping contains a date element which looks something like this

```
7 april 2022 19:00 - 8 april 04:00 utc+02
```

I have already figured out how to pull the start day and both of the months, I am however having some trouble pulling the military times as well as the second day.

I'm thinking that I have to use the `%` operator in some way when searching for the military time but couldn't find much online and its been a while since I used python.

For the pulling of the second day I tried to do the same thing as I did when taking the first one the problem is however that i end up pulling the `"02"` from the `"utc+02"`.

Thanks for any help I can get!

```
time = temp[0]  # the content of scraping

        emp_str = ""
        f_digit = False
        for d in time:  # finds the first digit(s) aka the day
            if d.isdigit():
                emp_str = emp_str+d
                f_digit = True
            elif f_digit:
                break
        s_day = emp_str
        emp_ar = []
        s_month = ""
        e_month = ""
        for m in MONTHS:  # this finds the months in the string and adds their index for comparing MONTHS contains the months aka apr jun jul and so on
            index = time.find(m)
            if index != -1:
                emp_ar.append(m)
                emp_ar.append(index)

        if len(emp_ar) > 2:
            print("happened")
            # checks which index is bigger aka which one is mentioned first
            if int(emp_ar[1]) < int(emp_ar[3]):
                s_month = emp_ar[0]
                e_month = emp_ar[2]
            else:
                s_month = emp_ar[2]
                e_month = emp_ar[0]
        elif len(emp_ar) > 0:
            s_month = emp_ar[0]
            e_month = emp_ar[0]
        # puts the month in s/e month for start/end
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: `7 april 2022 19:00 - 8 april 04:00 utc+02` is a bit weird format because first date contains year but doesn't contain timezone offset and second date doesn't contain year but contains timezone offset. Are you sure that sample you've provided representing your data correctly?

Comment: just did another scrape, the thing is that i get some different formats but the most common one is indeed ```Lördag 9 apr 2022 kl. 21:00-19 jun kl. 12:00 UTC+02``` sorry for the swedish Lördag means saturday and kl. stands for well nothing really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [datetime.datetime.strptime()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) method.

In the comments the format seems to have changed but going off the original format your code would have to look like this:

```
from datetime import datetime

s = '7 april 2022 19:00 - 8 april 04:00 utc+02'
s = s.split('-')

startdate = datetime.strptime(s[0].strip(), '%d %B %Y %H:%M')
enddate = datetime.strptime(s[1].strip()+'00', '%d %B %H:%M utc%z')
startdate = startdate.replace(tzinfo=enddate.tzinfo)
enddate = enddate.replace(year=startdate.year)
```

Edited to transfer the start year to the end year

Comment: Okay that seems much simpler than what i have been doing so far, thank you. I am however concerned of what might happen if the string looks wrong? the thing is as stated above that im collecting data from 13 sorority/fraternities and they are really bad at doing things the same way. so whilst this works on maybe 70% what would happen if eg they put saturday in the front or some random kl. in there or if they left out the month/second day in the end date?

Comment: Even if between them they are different, does each one always do it the same way?

Comment: yeah thats a great point actually. the only thing they really do different in-house is that they sometimes dont have an end time. but i think i can sort that out myself. but for curiosity how would i go about handling a random kl. in the middle? the random saturday im thinking i can handle by just removing the beggining of the string until it starts with a number/digit right?

Comment: For the kl. in the middle you could call `s[0].replace(' kl.', '')` to get rid of it

Comment: yeah of course big thanks!

Comment: and yes to remove the saturday you could either keep removing a character from the start until `s[0].isdigit() == True`, or you could look for the first character after a space: `s[0] = s[0][s[0].strip().index(' ')+1:]`